# linear fit on log-log plot isn't linear

Tags: python, statistics, linear-regression

I'm trying to analyse reproducibility of one experiment. I replaced 0 values with 0.1 and I plotted data from both experiments with log-log axes. So far, so good.

Next, I got rows where values in both columns are > 0 and I calculated a linear regression on the log10 of those values. I got the slope and the intercept of the linear fit and then I tried to plot it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

table = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
data = table.replace(0, 0.1)
plt.plot(data["run1"], data["run2"], color="#03012d", marker=".", ls="None", markersize=3, label="")

plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.axis('square')
plt.xlabel("1st experiment")
plt.ylabel("2nd experiment")

from scipy.stats import linregress

df = table.loc[(table['run1'] >0) & (table['run2'] >0)]

stats = linregress(np.log10(df["run1"]),np.log10(df["run2"]))

m = stats.slope
b = stats.intercept
r = stats.rvalue

x = np.logspace(-1, 5, base=10)
y = (m*x+b)

plt.plot(x, y, c='orange', label="fit")
plt.legend()
```

But this is what I get and it's definitely not linear:
[image: plot]

I don't know what I am doing wrong..

**EDIT:**

Link to the initial [dataset](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/7bfaf7adc168e824a2258c003ebf0e0e20181207203507/440225)

Comment: Well, you've created a line y = m x + b and plotted that, but m x + b won't be a line since the axes are logarithmic. Try plotting y = m log(x) + b or maybe log(y) = m log(x) + b (not sure, you'll have to sort it out).

Comment: I tried to replace `x` with `np.log10(x)` (same for `y`) but it only produced even weirder lines..

Comment: Would you please post a link to the raw data?

Comment: @JamesPhillips Yes of course, I edited the question and added a link to download it !

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing things here. The problem is that `np.logspace(-1, 5, base=10)` simply returns you logarithmically spaced values but you still need to take the base 10 log of your x-values because your x-axis in the plot is logarithmic *(np.log10(x))* and do the following

```
x = np.log10(np.logspace(-1, 5, base=10))
y = (m*x + b)
plt.plot(x, y, c='orange', label="fit")
```

This will give you what you expect, a straight linear regression prediction.

Comment: This gives me an even weirder output (see [https://i.stack.imgur.com/htRJ5.png] ).

Comment: Can you try `x = np.logspace(-1, 5, base=10)` and then `plt.plot(x, np.log10(y), c='orange', label="fit")`

Comment: Yes. It's still not a linear fit.. [https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHrYq.png]

Comment: Share some data so that I can try it myself

Comment: As requested by another user, I just edited the question and added a link to download the dataset I'm working on. Thanks for your help !

Comment: @FlorianBernard: How am I supposed to read the file into `table`? Please edit your code so that I can just directly use it to reproduce the plot

Comment: I edited the code but you just need `pandas.read_csv` to open a csv as a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

When I visually inspect a scatterplot of the data, I see no utility in taking logs. A straight line through the raw data looks like it is probably the best you can do here, see the attached images.
[image: scatter]

[image: linear]

Comment: The scatter plot with linear axis is too compressed. I managed to get that output as well with linear axis but the real problem here is with log-log axis. Thanks for looking into it but that's not the answer I needed.